# Prove differentiability of a function at a point without function defined

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations

I've been given the following problem:

Let $g:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ where $|g(x)| \leq |x|^2$. Prove that $g$ is differentiable at (0,0,...,0). Hint: Figure out what $Dg(0,...,0)$ must be and then show that it works.

How am I supposed to prove differentiability in this problem when the $g$ has not actually been defined?

I do not understand what I'm supposed to be gleaning from this inequality. All it says is that the length of the images of $g$ are less than the squared length of the pre-image.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $ g(0)=0$. You can easily guess that the derivative has to be $0$. For a proof apply the definition of derivative. You have to show that $\frac {\|g(x)\|} {\|x\|} \to 0$ as $\|x\|\to 0$ which is true.

Comment: just to be clear, why exactly is g(0)=0? Is it because, in order to get from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, $g$ must be defined as a linear combination of elements of an $\mathbb R^n$ vector (and so when you pass all 0s, the sum is 0)

Comment: @jmars $0 \leq |g(0)| \leq 0^{2}=0$ so $g(0)=0$.

Comment: after the $g(0)=0$ terms fall out, don't we want to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} {{g(x)- Dg(x)}\over ||x||}=0$. So shouldn't the derivative be $g(x)$?

Comment: @jmars You first guess that $Dg(0)=0$ and then prove that is is indeed the case. You are the left with showing that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {g{(x)}} {\|x\|} =0$.

Comment: more specifically, i mean, don't we want to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} {{g(0+x)-g(0)- Dg(x)}\over ||x||}= \lim_{x\to 0} {{g(x)- Dg(x)}\over ||x||}=0$